# Como se pueden imprimir los caracteres de formato de string en C?

Tags: c, string

Necesito una manera de escapar los caracteres de formateo de strings

Por ejemplo:

Tengo este código:

```
printf("%d %d",15);
```

Si yo quisiera imprimir `%d 15` ,como lo haría?

Comment: Muchas gracias ;)

Comment: `printf("%%d %d",15);` El "%" actua como escape.

Comment: @CandidMoe ¿ Porqué no escribes una respuesta ? Entre la explicación de como escapar caracteres y alguna básico de los indicadores de formato, da para una completita :-)

Comment: @Trauma. Es algo que ni siquiera debería preguntarse ...

Comment: @CandidMoe replantéatelo, si publicas tu respuesta elimino la mía.

Comment: @CandidMoe en el fondo [es.so] es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas y cuanto más material tenga (incluyendo algunos detalles básicos), más gente acudirá al sitio y más probable es que crezca y que acabe atrayendo a gente con conocimientos que se animen a contribuir (en vez de recibir casi en exclusiva gente con preguntas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te han dicho via comentarios, la solución es usar dos `%` seguidos:

```
printf("%%d %d", 15);
```